# Enable "Audit Process Tracking" from CMD regardless of the system language

Tags: windows, audit, local-security-policy

I want to edit the local security audit policy from the command line. From what I found out, there's `auditpol.exe` and I can set the policy using the "/set" parameter. This does indeed work, but there's one problem:

I need specify the category and subcategory by a string that is in the systems language. For example, my windows is set to german, therefore the command looks like this:

```
auditpol.exe /set /category:"detaillierte Nachverfolgung" /subcategory:"Prozesserstellung" /success:enable
```

"detaillierte Nachverfolgung" = detailed Tracking

"Prozesserstellung" = Process creation

When ever I try to use the english names, I get the error 0x00000057 (wrong parameter).

This is copyied from the official documentation from Microsoft:

```
Auditpol /set /category:"Detailed Tracking" /success:enable
```

If i execute this, I get the error mentioned above.

I need to be able to set the policy regardless of the users system language.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the guid, this is language agnostic. Example for account login and logon/logoff:

```
auditpol /set /category:"{69979849-797A-11D9-BED3-505054503030}" /success:enable /failure:enable
auditpol /set /category:"{69979850-797A-11D9-BED3-505054503030}" /success:enable /failure:enable
```

Get the list of guids by doing this:

```
auditpol /list /subcategory:* /r
```

Comment: This doesn't include the subcategories. For those, it's `auditpol /list /cubcategory:* /r` (the `/r` is needed because `auditpol` would omit the GUIDs without it).

Comment: ```auditpol /list /cubcategory:* /r``` Is not a valid command on my system.

Comment: Typo, fixed it.